# How to merge contents in the same node which belong to one xml file?

Tags: python, xml, merge, tags, document-root

Let's say, I have a xml file like this:

```
<recs>
<REC>
<SYS_TOPIC>topic1 topic1</SYS_TOPIC>
<SYS_AUTHORS>author1</SYS_AUTHORS>
<DOC_CONTENT>content1 content1 content1 content1 content1 content1 content1</DOC_CONTENT>
<DOC_WRITEDATE>2016-12-01 09:30:10</DOC_WRITEDATE>
</REC>

<REC>
<SYS_TOPIC>topic2 topic2</SYS_TOPIC>
<SYS_AUTHORS>author2</SYS_AUTHORS>
<DOC_CONTENT>content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content1</DOC_CONTENT>
<DOC_WRITEDATE>2016-12-01 09:30:10</DOC_WRITEDATE>
</REC>
</recs>
```

What if I wanna merge all the contents in the tag of `<DOC_CONTENT>` together in one? I tried `root.findall('DOC_CONTENT').text` But it consoles `'list' object has no attribute 'text'`

Comment: Can you give an example of required output?

Comment: @nick_gabpe I want the out put like this: 
'<DOC_CONTENT>content1 content1 content1 content1 content1 content1 content1content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content1</DOC_CONTENT>' just put all the contents in <DOC_CONTENT> in the same tag is fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

source_xml = """<recs>
<REC>
<SYS_TOPIC>topic1 topic1</SYS_TOPIC>
<SYS_AUTHORS>author1</SYS_AUTHORS>
<DOC_CONTENT>content1 content1 content1 content1 content1 content1 content1</DOC_CONTENT>
<DOC_WRITEDATE>2016-12-01 09:30:10</DOC_WRITEDATE>
</REC>

<REC>
<SYS_TOPIC>topic2 topic2</SYS_TOPIC>
<SYS_AUTHORS>author2</SYS_AUTHORS>
<DOC_CONTENT>content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content1</DOC_CONTENT>
<DOC_WRITEDATE>2016-12-01 09:30:10</DOC_WRITEDATE>
</REC>
</recs>"""
tree = et.fromstring(source_xml)
doc_content = "DOC_CONTENT"
content = [tr.text for tr in tree.iter() if (tr.tag ==doc_content)]
root = et.Element(doc_content)
root.text = ""
for el  in content:
    root.text += el
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried it! But why does it comes the name error: 'NameError: name 'root' is not defined' 
Thank you!

Comment: Because i forgot add row `root = et.Element(doc_content)`.
It should work now.

Comment: Can I add a following question? I got the right output. But it returns as two lists. How should I do if I want all the contents in one list? The ultimate aim of this is to count the top 3 frequent words of all the contents. Thank you!!

Comment: What did you mean? it returns only one `xml.etree.ElementTree.Element`. you can use `et.tostring(root)` and write it to file or what you want.

Comment: Maybe I can reiterate my question like this: When I write `print el[2]`, why does the output is 2 `n`s? It seems there are two variables in el. But what if I want merge them in one? I wish I clarified the question?

Comment: `el` is a string. Printing `el[2]` you just print second element in string. I still don't understand the question.

Comment: Because I want to count the top high frequently words for all the contents in tags together. But if I use the code below to do it. It count the top frequent words for each tag, which is not what I want. 

       `words = [word for word in jieba.cut(el, cut_all=True) if len(word) >= 2]
 c = Counter(words)
 for word_freq in c.most_common(1):
     word, freq = word_freq
     print(word, freq)`

Comment: Sorry I don't undersyand you. You can ask it separate question on SO.